# Could not reuse a function correctly on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a task to make a form validation, and all went seamlessly except for this one weird thing.

Basically, I have to show an error message below each input field if an error happened. The style for this error message has been made in the CSS file, so I just add necessary attribute when an error happened, like this:

```
//form validation onblur
//valid condition
var valid = true;
var message = "";

//function to add attribute to show error message
function showError(index) {
    formDataArr[index].setAttribute("data-error", message);
    formDataArr[index].setAttribute("data-error-visible", true);
};

//function to hide error when input is valid
function hideError(index) {
    formDataArr[index].removeAttribute("data-error");
    formDataArr[index].removeAttribute("data-error-visible");
};
```

So my idea is to use this function to show the error, and it works fine except for the last two elements for which the validation only happened when the submit button is clicked. Here is my validation on click code:

```
//function to validate form onsubmit
function validateForm () {
    valid = true;
    message = "";
    //first name validation
    validateFirstName();
    //last name validation
    validateLastName();
    //email validation
    validateEmail();
    //birthdate validation
    validateBirthdate();
    //quantity validation
    validateQuantity();

    //location radio button validation
    //Change the checkboxInput NodeList into an array
    var checkboxArray = Array.from(checkboxInput);
    //filter the checked input
    var checkboxInputChecked = checkboxArray.filter(input => input.checked);
    
    //put condition to check if a choice has been chosen
    if (checkboxInputChecked.length < 1) {
        valid = false;
        message = "Veuillez choisir une ville.";
        showError(5);
    } else {
        valid;
        hideError(5);
    };

    //T&C checkbox validation
    if (!checkbox1.checked) {
        valid = false;
        message = "Veuillez accepter les conditions d'utilisations."
        formDataArr[6].setAttribute("data-error", message);
        formDataArr[6].setAttribute("data-error-visible", true);
    } else {
        valid;
        hideError(6);
    };

    if (valid) {
        var successMessage = document.getElementById("formResult");
        var successMessageText = document.getElementById("formResultText");
        var message = "Merci ! Votre réservation a été reçu.";
        successMessageText.textContent = message;
        successMessage.style.display = "block";

    }
    return valid;
 };
```

You see in the location radio button validation (index 5), I tried to reuse the showError function, however, it wouldn't show the correct message, it will show the message from the index 4 instead. But, if I rewrite the whole code like on the index 6, it works fine. I failed to understand why is this happening and where do I do wrong with this function.

My github repo if you need further inspection: https://github.com/gndz07/GameOn-website-FR

Comment: Just as a suggestion: You can create a dedicated function to validate those checkboxes, as you have already done with `validateFirstName` and the rest of `validate*` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a global `message` variable, but I can't see if it is the same in the `showError` scope and in the `validateForm` scope. I suggest to NOT use the global variable, but to add an argument to `showError`.

Comment: @gndz07 Please, also up vote the answer ;)